# Creating subdomain for Samba to use url instead ip address

Tags: dns, samba, webserver, apache-virtualhost

I'm new to Linux, but I already have a grip on the basics.

I'm creating a simple local web which runs DHCP server, samba server, ftp server, webmail server (I use squirrelmail), DNS server and web server in a virtual machine of Debian 8.

I self taught for Linux things, and have run each of these programs smoothly, I created subdomain for webmail (mail.sitename.com) and the domain (sitename.com) served as the main web, but I want to make another subdomain for samba (ftp.sitename.com), so far I have not found the way to add it.

I tried to add the ftp subdomain in /etc/bind/db.local:

```
ftp    IN    A   ftp.sitename.com
```

But it always loads the home web (sitename.com) not the ftp subdomain. I also tried to add another VirtualHost in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

The code I added:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ftp.sitename.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@sitename.com
    DocumentRoot /etc/samba
</VirtualHost>
```

If I used the 'add virtualhost', whenever I input ftp.sitename.com it gives

> 403 FORBIDDEN    You don't have permission to access / on this server

Comment: Possible file permissions on `/etc/samba`. Are you trying to list all the files in `/etc/samba` in a web browser? If so, you may need to also add `Options Indexes` to the `VirtualHost` entry. See: [403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /folder-name/ on this server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948996/403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-folder-name-on-this-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you increased the zone serial after changing its content? It is mandatory, and you need to reload the name server
2. After changing the Apache configuration, you need to reload it
3. If you have permission error, have a look at Apache's `error.log` file it will give you more information on what is wrong. Are you sure that the user under which Apache runs can access `/etc/samba/` ?

Comment: ah, yes.. my mistake, i forgot to add zone in the bind9 of DNS, now it works like a charm, thank you!